# With Python, how can I convert a flac stream to a wav stream?

Tags: python, stream, pyaudio

I know that I can use `PyAudio` to convert a `.flac` file to a `.wav` file. But I'm wondering if I can somehow do it as a stream and not have to save the `.wav` file?

Currently, I have:

```
stream = open('84-121123-0000.flac', 'rb')
```

But I want to convert that stream to a `wav` file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Just to be clear, I don't want to save a `.wav` file. Instead, I want to keep a stream of the `wav` converted content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, you can install `ffmpeg`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

In Windows: download `ffmpeg` at: [FFMPEG Download](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html), set up environment variables at `Edit the system environment variables` , `Path`, `New`, `C:\ffmpeg\bin\`

Then run in Python:

```
import os
os.system('ffmpeg -i inputfile.flac output.wav')
```

You can use this output as a temp file, with a 3-5 seconds delay.

Comment: No Mac support?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `pydub` lib that it's easy to do the function what you need:

```py
from pathlib import PurePath
from pydub import AudioSegment

file_path = PurePath("test.flac")

flac_tmp_audio_data = AudioSegment.from_file(file_path, file_path.suffix[1:])

flac_tmp_audio_data.export(file_path.name.replace(file_path.suffix, "") + ".wav", format="wav")
```

The [Documentation](https://pydub.com/).

Comment: Except I don't want to export to a file. I want to keep the stream that I would have gotten from `open`

Comment: You could try to export it to a temp file and then re-open it

Comment: You can use the `io.StringIO` or another io

Comment: Exporting to a file isn't an option for me currently

Comment: The last line can just be `flac_tmp_audio_data.export(file_path.with_suffix(".wav"))`.

Comment: @TomSwirly on my end, I had to add `, format="wav` for the file to be playable: `flac_tmp_audio_data.export(file_path.with_suffix(".wav"), format="wav")`

Comment: Thanks @RTD!  This was so long ago I don't remember it, but good tip.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `pydub` without needing to save a file, by using `io.BytesIO`:

```py
import io
from pydub import AudioSegment


flac = AudioSegment.from_file('/path/to/84-121123-0000.flac', format='flac')
stream = io.BytesIO()
flac.export(stream, format='wav')
```